# C# WebApi This localhost page can’t be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

recently I create one project webapi, platform ubuntu 22.04, so I'm using  visual studio code to runn it, pressing f5, but I'm getting this issue:

```
This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:5166/
HTTP ERROR 404
```

this is the file configuration:

[image]

[image]

what's wrong??

[image: console]

Comment: Please add console output from your VS code for more informations.

Comment: if it's a webapi, there might be nothing on the default route. The swagger page should be available and there should be some outpout calling your WeatherForecast controller. Try http://localhost:5166/swagger or http://localhost:5166/WeatherForecast

Comment: I test  it with  ```localhost:5166/swagger or localhost:5166/WeatherForecast``` but don't work, this is so strange